# Google Maps Java API - Linking API key

Tags: java, html, api, google-maps, security

I'm currently learning Google maps Java API

This might be a stupid question, but I noticed that the documentation recommends linking to the API key like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
</script>
```

I realise you can restrict your API usage by domain, but is there a safer way of linking this? Or should I just not argue with google?

Thanks heaps,

Kieran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to the same question a few weeks ago, and you should not argue with google. You can restrict the domains that can access your api key in your google api console, so if you have a repository on github, you can restrict it to your username, like username.github.io/*, but that will also block you it in your localhost(unless you get a static IP, then you can whitelist it locally), so I recommend just keeping it to yourself, and restricting if you want to share your code with the world.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have mention above is correct way to link API key and if you want your key should be secure you can Restrict your API key from the console to provide more security.

you can refer below link for more clarification:

https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices